# Rename PDF extracted Pages File from a Single Booklet PDF in correct sequence

Tags: java

I have huge PDF files which are in booklet format.

example,

Assume a booklet pdf file has 24 pages which each page contains 2 pages which is in two sides  - left side and right side.

The first page has 48th page number on the left side and 1st page number on the right side
The second page has 2nd page number on the left side and 47th page number on the right side
The third page has 46th page number on the left side and 3rd page number on the right side

I have vertically cut the Booket PDF files in to separate individual PDF files using bulk operation in separate folder.

for example, the cutted PDF file will be as follows in the above case

1st pdf file - 48th page
2nd pdf file - 1st page
3rd pdf file - 2nd page
4th pdf file - 47th page
5th pdf file - 46th page
6th pdf file - 3rd page..

Similarly for other PDF files too....if a PDF file has 95 pages....

the first page has 95th page number on the left side and 1st page number on the right side

Now the issue is how to rename and arrange the files correctly in the sequence for EACH PDF file so that we can merge the PDF file as one at last for each PDF file...

After renaming correctly in the proper sequence for the above file

1st pdf file should point to 1st page
2nd pdf file should point to 2nd page
3rd pdf file should point to 3rd page...

The problem is all the PDF files which we are planning to split will have different set of pages..example

PDF1 file - has 48 pages as above -> files should be renamed and arranged as 1, 2, 3, 4...48 correctly
PDF2 file - has 96 pages -> files should be renamed and arranged as 1, 2, 3, 4.....96 correctly
PDF3 file - has 56 pages -> files should be renamed and arranged as 1, 2, 3, 4.....56 correctly

Could someone help me with a program which will rename the vertically cutted files in a proper sequence??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We aren't going to write you a program from scratch! Have you tried anything? If so, show us what you have and your problems with it. If not, as I said at the beginning we aren't going to write you a whole program, thats not what this site is for!

Comment: where i need to post this programming help questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the problem if the number of pages are Even.....Below is the code for your reference...assume the number of pages is 32

How about if the number of pages is ODD ???

package sample;

import java.io.File;

public class sample {

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    String fileNameStartsWith = "_pdfsam_pdf_";
    String dir = "D:\\files\\";
    String destDir = "D:\\dest\\";  
    int totalPages = 32;
    int loops = totalPages/2;
    boolean pickFirst = true;
    int pageNbr1 = 0;
    int pageNbr2 = 0;
    int count = 1;
    for(int i=1; i <= loops; i++) {
        if(pickFirst == true) {
            pageNbr1 = totalPages;
            pageNbr2 = i;
            pickFirst = false;

totalPages--;
        } else {
            pageNbr1 = i;
            pageNbr2 = totalPages;
            totalPages--;
            pickFirst = true;
        }           
        System.out.println("PageNbr 1 "+pageNbr1);
        System.out.println("PageNbr 2 "+pageNbr2);
        File dest = new File(destDir);
        dest.mkdirs();
        File file1 = new File(dir + pageNbr1+fileNameStartsWith+".pdf");            
        renameFile(file1, dir, count, fileNameStartsWith, destDir, pageNbr1);
        count++;
        File file2 = new File(dir + pageNbr2+fileNameStartsWith+".pdf");
        renameFile(file2, dir, count, fileNameStartsWith, destDir, pageNbr2);
        count++;

    }

}


public static void renameFile(File file, String dir, int count, String fileNameStartsWith, String destDir, int pageNbr) {
    boolean success = new File(dir + count+fileNameStartsWith+".pdf").renameTo(new File(destDir + pageNbr+fileNameStartsWith+"modified"+".pdf"));
    System.out.println("success2 : "+success);                      
}
```

}